# Show Button over a bitmap not imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have a full screen activity that is used to show the advertisement. Advertisement is just a image and there is a cross button over the image. Everything seems to work fine the only issue I am facing is when the image coming from server is in landscape mode then cross button remains at top and image at center[image]

When image is in portrait mode then image comes in full screen and cross at the top

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how to move cross button over the image loaded like in second image for landscape images.

Here is my code

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.adimage);
    try {
        obj = new JSONObject(store.getString(Constants.PROFILE_STRING));
        JSONObject advert = obj.getJSONObject("advertisement");
        url = advert.getString("url");
        image = advert.getString("image");
        name = advert.getString("name");
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .cacheOnDisc(true)
                .build();
        il.loadImage(image, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                img.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                findViewById(R.id.close).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is my layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context="soulvant.golfclub.Advertisement">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <!--<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/adimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/adimage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/adimage"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/a_close_button"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you want cross on the image.right?

Comment: What you use for showing adv? Means dialog?

Comment: its a full screen activity

Answer (score 0):

**Well, you can do it this way.**

> Get the width and height of the adImage when it's downloaded
>
> Then, place the close button/image on the adImage, specifying the location where you want to place the image

Answer (score 0):

Try by keep `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your imageview this property adjust image bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.do like:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/adimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```